# C# MVC mark textarea required based on specific selected dropmenu value across multiple drop menus

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

Long shot here, but I don't even know where to start.  I maintain an MVC site.  The form features several dozen drop menus.  Rather than type them all out manually in the view, I'm generating them in loops.

Drop Menu options:

```
List<string> menuList = new List<string>() { "Correct", "Incorrect", "N/A" };
```

Drop Menu names (one of several lists on the page):

```
List<string> auditList1 = new List<string>() { "AE_FIRST","AE_SECOND","AE_THIRD", ... ,"AE_NTH"};
```

And here's the code to generate the drop menus:

```
@foreach (string audElement in auditList1)
{
    string selected = "";
    dropMenuCount = 0;
    bool menuItemMatched = false;
    <tr>
        <td>@audElement:  </td>
        <td>
            <select name="@audElement">
                @foreach (string menuElement in menuList)
                {
                    selected = "";
                    if (Model.AuditFound == true
                        && auditElementCount < 45
                        && menuElement == auditArray[auditElementCount].ToString()
                        && menuItemMatched == false)
                    {
                        selected = "selected";
                        auditElementCount++;
                        menuItemMatched = true;
                    }
                    if (menuElement == null)
                    {
                        auditElementCount++;
                    }
                    if (dropMenuCount == 2 && menuItemMatched == false)
                    {
                        selected = "selected";
                    }
                    dropMenuCount++;
                    <option value=@menuElement @selected>@menuElement</option>
                }
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

So that's the setup.  I did it this way because I'm working with an old, flat Oracle table that has 64 columns that I'm not allowed to change.  Works as intended.  They use the same form to enter a new audit or to review an existing audit, so that's the reason for the @selected logic.

The business unit is asking me to make a comments box mandatory if the user selects "Incorrect" for ANY of the drop menus.

```
<textarea name="AUDIT_COMMENTS" cols="66" rows="6">@audit_comments</textarea>
```

Best way to go about this?

Comment: Are we talking about making them required without refreshing page? Or form is generated after dropdown is selected in next page?

Comment: Making the textarea required without refreshing, yes.  Some sort of client-side validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo,when one of the dropdownlists' values is incorrect,add required to textarea,otherwise,remove required.

View:

```
<form id="myform" method="post">
    @foreach (string audElement in Model.auditList1)
    {
        <div>
            <label>@audElement</label>
            <select>
                <option value="Correct">Correct</option>
                <option value="Incorrect">Incorrect</option>
                <option value="N/A"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    }
    <textarea id="audit_comments" name="AUDIT_COMMENTS" cols="66" rows="6"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
<style>
    .error {
        color:red;
    }
</style>
```

js:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(function () {
            check();
        })
        $("#myform").validate();
        $("select").change(function () {
            check();
        });
        function check() {
            var required = false;
            $("select").each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == "Incorrect") {
                    required = true;
                }
            })
            $('#audit_comments').attr('required', required);
        }
       
    </script>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful,can you accept it as answer?Thank you.